# Using rvest, is it possible to click a tab that activates a div and reveals new content for scraping

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm new to rvest and I'm trying to determine if its possible to use rvest to click a tab that activates a div so that data can be scraped.  I've been reading the [rvest documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) on cran and have not read anything that talks about clicking links, buttons or tabs.

The site that I'm interested in scraping is: [touch.tvg.com](http://touch.tvg.com)

From the home page I'd like to click the race button (Again, how do you clik buttons in rvest)

Next, I'd like to select an upcoming race.  This should redirect me to the selected race's url. For example: [The 10th race at Hoosier](https://touch.tvg.com/race/HOO/Twi/10)

Once one the race page, I'd like to click the Pool tab and scrape the pool information.

I've attached some screen shots below.  Any suggestion, guidance is appreciated.

From Home Page - Click Races Button
[image: Home Page - Click Races]

From Races Page - Click an upcoming Race
[image: Races Page - Click an upcoming race]

From The Particular Race Page - Click The Pool Tab
[image: From the Race Page - Click the pool tab]

With the Pool data (Div) visible - Scrape the Pool Data.
[image: With Pool data visible - Scrape Pool Data]

Comment: No. You'd need RSelenium, which is a little complicated.

Comment: If you figure this out will you be able to predict which horse is going to win?

Comment: @Hack-R I have read some post that indicate it is possible to accomplish this with rvest. As I recall ( I can't find the article now) the writer suggest using chrome dev tools and network to identify what's being sent to the server and then basically replicate it.  I don't know if that applies to the divs on this page.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor That sounds about right.

Comment: Mutuelinvestor - Would you accept an `RSelenium` answer?

Comment: You can check this url https://touch.tvg.com/ajax/races/track/GB1/performance/Day/get/collection for (GB1 needs to be replaced by the race you are interested in), it has all the data for all the days of each race. Also, is scraping allowed in their TOS?

Comment: It looks like this is about solving the problem that this Upwork job poses: https://www.upwork.com/jobs/_~017b02239f5c37db01/.

Comment: @NicE would you like to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSelenium seems to offer all the functionality needed to harvest the data of interest.  The best results might be achieved by combining the strength of rselenium with those of rvest.

Thank to everyone for their comments.